# getting the content inside href using selenium python

Tags: python, database, selenium, web-scraping

```
`PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
 driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
 for x in range (1,25):
    url='http://catalog.aucegypt.edu/content.php?catoid=36&catoid=36&navoid=1738&filter%5Bitem_type%5D=3&filter%5Bonly_active%5D=1&filter%5B3%5D=1&filter%5Bcpage%5D='+str(x)+'#acalog_template_course_filter'


    driver.get(url)
     Courses_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="width"]/a')

    

      #print(course_Prerequisites)
#num_courses=len(Courses_names)
#for i in range(num_courses):
    #print(Courses_names[i].text)


   for i in Courses_names:
    print(i.text)       
    hrefs=i.get_attribute('href')
    print(hrefs)
    
    course_content=hrefs.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="block_content"]')
    print(course_content.text)




    driver.close()`
```

I need to  get the content inside of Herf, but this error comes up    course_content=hrefs.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="block_content"]/a')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Comment: Please check your URL, is it correct because it is showing resource not found error.

Comment: url='http://catalog.aucegypt.edu/content.php?catoid=36&catoid=36&navoid=1738&filter%5Bitem_type%5D=3&filter%5Bonly_active%5D=1&filter%5B3%5D=1&filter%5Bcpage%5D='+str(x)+'#acalog_template_course_filter'

Answer (score 0):

The href is just a string containing the url this link is pointing to, it’s not a web element.

If you want to find in this page you have to first get the page and then find the element

```py
hrefs = []
for i in Courses_names:
    print(i.text)       
    href=i.get_attribute('href')
    hrefs.append(href)
    print(href)
for url in hrefs:
    driver.get(url)
    course_content=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="block_content"]')
    print(course_content.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that deep in selenium, but I try to describe my thoughts to your problem.

**Understanding**

1. URL now seems to be correct (thanks @Swaroop Humane), so that you can get the list of courses
2. You also should get each course name and url
3. Now you want to get the description / content of the course

**Think about**

To access details / description of a course you have to click the link, because there is no "content" element provided in the source code of the page by default. It will be added by JS onclick event.

**What you can do**

Try to use [find_element_by_link_text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text):

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(i.text)
```

To click on it, just call [click method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/):

```
link.click()
```

Now you should look for a new added table with `class="td_dark"` that contains course details. Appearing of the element may takes some ms, so you should take a look with delay ([selenium waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html))

Hope that helps, let us know.

Comment: would it be okay to explain more

Comment: @Nour Gamal - Did you give it a try? What should I explain in detail?